# projective $K$ -plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, projective-geometry, projective-space

I came across the following statement that in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ "$1$- planes are lines and $2$- planes are hyperplanes".

What is the precise definition of "K - planes " in a projective space  $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ ?

Can someone give me a reference?

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: Let $V$ be an $n+1$ dimension vector space.  Denote by $\mathbb{P}V$ the corresponding $n$-dimensional projective space. A $k$-plane is the image of a $k+1$-dimensional subspace of $V$ under the quotient map $V-\{0\}\to\mathbb{P}V$. This is probably discussed in Joe Harris' book on algebraic geometry.

Comment: I feel like usually a "$k$-plane" would be called a $k$-flat, but this definition can be found in lots & lots of places. Where did you come across the statement? Did it give any references for background material?